# MVC Controller return RedirectToAction Id + #id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Hello im trying to redirect the user to the blog section and it works fine but i want the user to land on bottom of site section  ( #section-variants ) 
but i cant figure out what im doing wrong is there any other way of passing it along

```
public ActionResult BlogComment_Delete(int? id, int? postid)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                Notification model = db.Notifications.Find(id.Value);
                if (model != null)
                {
                    db.Notifications.Remove(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", "Blog", new { Id = postid + "#section-variants" });
        }
```

Comment: http://localhost:12689/Blog/BlogPost/34%23section-variants

is where i land. i have no idea where it gets the %23 from? insted of #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another method - [`RedirectResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("BlogPost", "Blog", new { Id = postid }) + "#section-variants");
```